# How does AngularJS distinguish between the following actions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose `this.model === $scope.model`.

The following will trigger a digest:

```
$scope.model.property1.property2 = true;
```

but this won't without a watch:

```
this.model.property1.property2 = true;
```

How does AngularJS distinguish between these two lines of code?

Comment: Can you clarify a little more? A digest processes asyncQueue on scopes and traverses scope to iterate watches. What do you mean by one will trigger a digest and one will not? I set up a fiddle that uses both of these lines within ng-click and both trigger a digest and update property2. http://jsfiddle.net/11j8vpL8/

Comment: OK, so my understanding is wrong. Both will trigger a digest? There must have been some extenuating circumstances in the actual code.

Comment: Digests are triggered within angular code (e.g. ng-click triggers a digest, typing into an ng-model input, etc.) or from "outside" angular code through scope.$apply(). Can you provide code where one piece of code exhibits different behavior than the other via jsfiddle? In my last fiddle the interpolation ({{model.property1.property2}}) puts a watch on that property, so it doesn't matter if it is updated via this or $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do my best to answer the question as it stands. There is nothing that would cause a digest to happen with either of these lines:

```
$scope.model.property1.property2 = true;
this.model.property1.property2 = true;
```

Both of these are simple assignment. Digests are triggered from code that explicitly calls it. This usually happens through either $scope.$eval(), $scope.$apply(), and explicit $scope.$digest() calls. For example, an ng-click binds to the elements click event and calls $scope.$apply() with the function attached to that directive.

The $digest loop first executes the expressions to evaluate on the asyncQueue of the scope (populated by $scope.$evalAsync() for instance). Next, it traverses the scopes and evaluates what watches need to be triggered and calls the appropriate functions assigned to them (if it finds a change).

So a couple points to take away that relate back to your question:

- Both lines above would not trigger a $digest
- Angular doesn't need to distinguish between the two lines of code because they are both simple assignment to the same property (assuming this.model === $scope.model as was stated in the question). Even if this.model and $scope.model were different, it is still just simple assignment, but to different destinations.
- Watches "fire" within a $digest loop as the scopes are traversed.

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/11j8vpL8/) demonstrates this from a high level. Notice there are no explicit watches put on either $scope.model.property1.property2 or this.model.property1.property2. The view is updated because both assignments happen in separate ng-clicks, which triggers a $digest loop. The {{model.property1.property2}} in the view sets up a watch on this value which is updated through each ng-click when $digest happens.

Without seeing the code example where actual differences are happening, I can't say why one behaves different than the other.